# C# file line remove with arraylist

Tags: c#, file, arraylist

I am trying to make a class which will help me delete one specific line from a file. So I came up with the idea to put all lines in an arraylist, remove from the list the line i don't need, wipe clear my .txt file and write back the remaining objects of the list. My problem is that I encounter some sort of logical error i can't fint, that doesn't remove the line from the arraylist and writes it back again. Here's my code:

```
public class delete
{
    public void removeline(string line_to_delete)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("database.txt");
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(lines);
        list.Remove(line_to_delete);
        File.WriteAllText("database.txt", String.Empty);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("database.txt"))
        {
            foreach (object k in lines)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is that I am missing? I tried lots of things on removing a line from a text file that did not work. I tried this because it has the least file operations so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Code should work. Most likely line is actually not present *exactly* in the file. Please provide sample data inline in the post (stick to [MCVE] guidelines when posting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
var line_to_delete = "line to delete";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("database.txt");
File.WriteAllLines("database.txt", lines.Where(line => line != line_to_delete));
```

`File.WriteAllLines` will overwrite the existing file.

Do not use `ArrayList`, there is a generic alternative `List<T>`. Your code is failing due to the use of `ArrayList` as it can only remove a single line matching the criteria. With `List<T>` you can use `RemoveAll` to remove all the lines matching criteria.

If you want to do the comparison with ignore case you can do:

```
File.WriteAllLines("database.txt", lines.Where(line => 
            !String.Equals(line, line_to_delete, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Why not use `String.Compare` rather than `String.Equals`?

Comment: @Greg, `String.Compare` is used for determining the relative position in the sort order *(which string is bigger)* etc. Here we are doing the string equality comparison ignoring case, there is an overload available for that in `String.Equals`. *(I used to make the same mistake since coming from C/C++ background, but now I use `string.Equals`)*.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.  Learned something new about the two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're intending:

```
public static void RemoveLine(string line)
{
     var document = File.ReadAllLines("...");
     document.Remove(line);
     document.WriteAllLines("..");
}
```

That would physically remove the line from the collection.  Another approach would be to simply filter out that line with Linq:

```
var filter = document.Where(l => String.Compare(l, line, true) == 0);
```

You could do the `Remove` in an `ArrayList` proper documentation on how is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove(v=vs.110).aspx). Your code should actually work, all of these answers are more semantic oriented.  The issue could be due to actual data, could you provide a sample?  I can't reproduce with your code.